# Why does providing key={index} result in different behavior than defining no key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Things *do* work if we define `key={index}` and *do not* work if we exclude it, but I would expect the behavior to be the same based on the docs.

[According to the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't providing no key be the equivalent of providing `key={index}`?

Comment: If you scroll down just a bit from your link, there's a link to [an in-depth explanation about why keys are necessary](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't address the question. If it auto-assigns index as the key, then why does explicitly providing `key={index}` result in different behavior, is the question.

Comment: Actually, it perfectly does. It states that it uses the key as a sort of look up tool to know what position items should be when rendering. That's the entire point of the in-depth explanation.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of a difference in behavior?

Comment: React uses _its own internal indexing_ based on the virtual DOM that it needs to build when you omit a key. Also, _never use iteration indexes as keys_, use an actually unique-to-that-element value as key. The whole point is that the key uniquely identifies _that element_ in a set of elements for React's differ to do its job properly.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you provide some documentation, discussion, or related React sourcecode? If so, please do submit that as an answer and I will happily accept it.

Comment: A lot of folks are reading your question wrong: you should probably rephrase it. Make it so that folks _can't_ misread what you're saying: you want to know about how key={index} vs no key is different, so just remove all the talk about bisecting and bugs and phrase it as such. "The docs say X, but those seem to be the same case, how do they differ".

Comment: I did in fact read it and from experience know that regardless of what the docs say it is unstable not providing a key. I've forgotten them (as I'm sure plenty of people do) and had things work for a while and then all of a sudden get an internal error about missing keys. My statement about just accepting it still stands

Comment: That's a pretty bad edit: things work in both cases, just not fine (neither omited keys or keys set to index values "work fine", they instead waste a ton of React's time applying diffs that aren't diffs), and certainly not predictably. You ran into a case where not having a key seemed to not behave the same as having a `key={index}`, so show a [mcve] that replicates that, and show folks the text in the docs that seems to imply they are the same.

Comment: When mapping data you should provide a unique React key, period. Are the docs clear enough on why a React key is useful?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the definition of "works fine" is it behaves correctly, not optimally. It works _correctly_ when including an index for a key, and works _incorrectly_ when excluding that line. If I knew how to recreate the issue easily then this would be a lot easier to get an answer for, yeah...

Comment: that is very much not "the" definition of working fine. React wasting time constantly tearing down and rebuilding identical data wastes cpu time, clock time, memory, needlessly burns through battery on mobile devices, etc. and so does not work fine at all. It works, it does not work fine, and it's _certainly_ not how you're supposed to use React. You're getting all this backlash because your question just doesn't follow the general form of [a good question](/help/how-to-ask): explain what you're doing, what you expected (with that docs link: it's a good link), and what you got instead.

Comment: Don't lecture folks on misreading you in your post: just update it to explain what's going on, and how that seems to be in conflict with the docs, and you'll get reasonable responses. And possibly even answers.

Comment: No, I have read the React documentation regarding lists and keys and understand it well enough. You're asking about a case that React recommends shouldn't be used. I'm pointing out that you are asking why the not-recommended usage doesn't work as *you* expect it to. If you believe otherwise, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your question/issue.

Comment: The docs *do say* "If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.", however they don't claim them to be the indexes of the array being mapped. Assuming them to be the same is an error. React code is open source, you're free to dig around in it if you like, but asking others to do the digging is a little unsatisfactory.

Comment: @DrewReese I didn't show up here asking anyone to dig for me. I showed up asking if someone knew what was going on, and someone claimed to. I asked them for any of multiple ways of showing that was the case. They showed it. I accepted the answer. The end.

Comment: Okay, so after 4 people citing the docs that it's "bad", 6 people downvoting, I'm still curious: What does React do if there's no key? Honestly I don't know, and I'd like to see a real answer to this question.

Comment: I agree, that the question was perhaps not phrased well, but don't understand the general non-understanding of the topic itself. The related docs paragraph has a clear contextual association to "array index", yet people claim the chosen key will not be the array index, making it an error in the react docs, which is interesting.

Comment: FWIW, the implementation is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c1536795cae5101041ef50a59ae29119aa1c2bf4/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js#L63)

Comment: "Things do work if we define key={index} and do not work if we exclude it" as far as I can see from a quick dive into the sourcecode, at least for the newest React version they're exactly the same. I'd really be curious to see an [mre], I can't explain what you're describing.

Comment: @charlietfl For what it's worth, `<div><div></div></div>` is not using keys (explicitly), yet it is totally fine React

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are ill-phrased: React [does not actually use a key](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L355-L383) if you don't specify one, and leaving off the key attribute is *not* the same as using `key={index}`. Instead, React will do internal checks based on child index of elements in their virtual DOM parent if no key attribute exists. Those may (and often, will) be the same as your iteration index, but certainly not always, and relying on them being the same is going to lead to bugs.

For an example of when "iteration index" and "virtual DOM child index" are not the same, let's look at a situation where we're creating child elements from multiple input lists. If we don't specify `key` attributes, React will warn about missing keys, but everything will work as expected:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
      a: [1,2,3],
      b: [4,5,6]
   };
  }
  render() {
    const { a, b } = this.state;
    return <div>{
      a.map(e => <p>{e}</p>).concat(b.map(e => <p>{e}</p>))
    }div>;
  }
}
```

We get six key-less paragraphs, with content 1 through 6, as you'd imagine we'd get by just looking at the code.

However, if we follow React's advice and add `key` attributes, but we mistakenly use array indices as keys, [something you should never do](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318), things stop working as expected:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
      a: [1,2,3],
      b: [4,5,6]
   };
  }
  render() {
    const { a, b } = this.state;
    return <div>{
      a.map((e,index) => <p key={index}>{e}</p>)
       .concat(b.map((e, index) => <p key={index}>{e}</p>))
    }div>;
  }
}
```

this will now show *three* paragraphs with content 1 through 3, because the two array mappings yield elements *with* keys, but also with key *collisions*. As all the elements from `b` have keys that collide with elements from `a`, React will throw them away, and now you have a bug to hunt down.

Of course, if you're writing proper React, this is not a situation you would normally find yourself in. *Always* use keys, and *always* make sure they uniquely identify the elements you're mapping.

That said, I've filed https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/3732 to hopefully get that text updated to make it explicit that the text is *not* talking about the index of whatever iteration your code is running but its own internal child node index.

Comment: Big thank you! The code in question here is from a third party and we've sort of "borg'd" it into our repo. When we did try applying best practices for keys, it explodes, so we decided not to touch it for now. But during a minor refactor we removed the explicit `key={index}` based on the wording of the docs. This clears that up and I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: This answer is wrong. The path for the element is _exactly the same_ if an index is specified or not. "but certainly not always" what makes you think so?

Comment: If someone can provide a more complete answer, I'm open to accepting it. For now, I have to accept this to be true because I've experienced it. I really wish I knew how to make a simple repro though and really understand why this is the case.

Comment: @JonasWilms here you go: https://jsbin.com/qonoqadezi/1/edit?js,output -- feel free to convince yourself that this goes _completely wrong_ if you actually use indices as keys by changing both instances of `e => <p>{e}</p>` to `(e,i) => <p key={i}>{e}</p>` (the elements will now clobber each other, because there is key collision, and the data from `b` will never get rendered). As you can see, being convinced that "the path for the element is _exactly the same_ if an index is specified or not" is the way to bugs.

Comment: The key point is, what react does, when no keys are given. The docs state, that it will take the index of the element in the array (the final children array obviously, not some intermediate that will be concatenated). Your example may be what OP did wrong, but not what the debate is about (before people claimed the docs were wrong, i was actually considering downvoting the question, because i believed it just stated something false, without a reproducible example). People try hard to explain, why keys are very often necessary, and while that's nice and all, it's OT.

Comment: Except that "the final children array obviously" is clearly not obvious at all. To the point where it's probably worth someone filing a docs issue so that the React folks can make that explicit instead of having people guess at which index it's talking about.

Comment: Okay, right, so this only goes wrong if you actually _lie_ to React by setting colliding keys. With a simple `arr.map((el, i) => <div key={i}>{el}</div>)` you [cannot create that scenario](https://jsbin.com/hewicaqidi/2/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: No, of course not, if you could create this scenario with a single map() this problem would have surfaced way back when React was still zero dot minor. And so, to literally quote myself from this answer: "Those may (and often, will) be the same as your iteration index, but certainly not always" because React doesn't use the index inherent to your iteration code, it uses the child index of virtual elements in its virtual dom. Unlike what the text implies when you know enough English to read documentation, but not enough React yet to know what the React folks meant with those words.

Comment: And of course, the code I've given you is the most concise form, what you _absolutely will_ encounter in the wild is things like `return <section>{ content }{ aside }</section>` when both are easy mappings, and if someone isn't in the habit of using proper keys, and they figure they should shut React up by adding `key={index}`, now they've run into the same bug without React telling them why. The OP could have done a much better job at writing their question, but their problem is certainly a real one.

Comment: I appreciate the enlightening discussion, code examples, and expanded answer. This makes it a bit easier to wrap my head around what's going on here.